Autocorrect Not Editable for a Given Language
After downloading the extension file, I need to go to Tools -> Extensions and use the 'Add' option to install it. I get a dialogue box asking if I want to install it for a "single" user or for all users.
However, if I double-click on the downloaded extension file, I do not get that dialog box, and the extension gets installed automatically. But, I cannot edit the autocorrect list. I noticed this issue while installing the extension:
https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/marathi-spellchecker
Is this a bug that needs to be reported?

Related to this bug? https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=117100
